# "CeleryTask matching query does not exist" when running Django tests

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm trying to test some part of a Django project. The test is:

```
class SearchTest(TestCase):
    def test_object_added(self):
            SomeSingleton().add_one_object_to_model()
            tmp = SomeModel.objects.latest('id')
            self.assertEqual(tmp.some_field,SOME_VALUE)
```

Here I'm calling some function to add somehow an object to a model. The creation model is related to some Celery task execution. The purpose of the test is to check a value of the field of the added model. So when an object is added to the model it becomes the latest by `id`.

I got this when I ran `./manage.py test some_app`:

> DoesNotExist: CeleryTask matching query does not exist.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454329/django-object-matching-query-does-not-exist-when-i-can-see-it-in-the-databas) here and tried to do the same thing. I changed `'id'` in `tmp = SomeModel.objects.latest('id')` to all the possible variants: `u'id'`, `u'"id"'` and even `u"id"` and `u"'id'"`. I was still getting the same issue to the variants with single quotation sign type. But I got

> FieldError: Invalid order_by arguments: [u'-"id"']

to the variants with both quotation sign types. It's alright, do we have any other ways to get the latest object of a model? I haven't found one that works. I tried to declare `get_latest_by = "id"` at `class Meta` but I got the same issue about query that doesn't exist.

I tried some Python ways (I still work with kind of a list, right?) like `tmp = SomeModel.objects.all()[-1]`, `SomeModel.objects.all()[len(SomeModel.objects.all())-1]` and the issue was

> AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.

Then I tried `SomeModel.objects.all().reverse()[0]` but was answered immediately:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I'm frankly baffled. All of these ways work good when typed at `./manage.py shell` so I can get the latest model but for some reason it doesn't happen when using `./manage.py test some_app`. What is the right way to cope with it?

Comment: `id` shouldn't be unicode, it should be an int so that question wouldn't apply to you. From the error message, it looks like the problem is that django can't find your celery task when running the tests. This `SomeSingleton().add_one_object_to_model()` is most likely the cause of your issues not `SomeModel.objects.latest('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always read documentation first. Reading [a part](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/unit-testing.html) of the one that comes to Celery did the trick; all what's needed was to add a

`TEST_RUNNER ='djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner'`

to `settings.py`. That was the reason the test couldn't get any of Celery task performing result.